# float + float = NAN

Tags: iphone, c, object

```
float jk = 7700;  float ck = 8000;  - if i do int jk;  I get rim=0;

printf (asin(jk/10500)) = 1.57897  - for example
printf (asin(ck/9500)) = 0.87868  - for example

float rim;
rim= asin(jk/10500)+ asin(ck/9500);

printf("\n%f", rim) = nan
```

Why i get nan?

Comment: I got correct(or at least valid) output, is it your actual code? And I got asin(0.5)=0.5235...

Comment: The second asin value is 0.8 on your machine?? Are you running this on Windows? :P

Comment: @Alexei, you need to post the _actual_ code. As everyone has stated, it seems to work okay (admittedly on other platforms).

Comment: @alexey: Edited my answer... still don't believe this is the ***actual*** code. At least because it doesn't compile. Can you PLEASE post a compilable code?!

Comment: Have you tried to heck the errno...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe your "for example". Because I don't believe in magic. If you have two valid floats both pretty small, then their sum is not a nan. So, my guess is this:

either `|jk| > 10500` or `|ck| > 9500`. So you make asin with an invalid ( > 1.0 or < -1.0) argument and thus get a nan.

Or you have made another error. Please post a compilable runnable example which will print NAN

Answer (score 4):

There's either something wrong with your code or something seriously wrong with the iphone. The following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main (void) {
    printf ("%f\n", asin(1));
    printf ("%f\n", asin(0.5));
    float rim;
    rim = asin(1) + asin (0.5);
    printf ("%f\n", rim);
    return 0;
}
```

produces a more sensible:

```
1.570796
0.523599
2.094395
```

In other words, both your `asin(0.5)` and your sum are incorrect.

Are you sure that you didn't actually do something like:

```
rim = asin(1 + asin (0.5));
```

That will indeed give you NaN.

---

Update based on your added info:

Your code still works fine in my environment:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main (void) {
    float jk = 7700;
    //jk = 7700/10500;
    jk = jk/10500;
    printf ("%f\n", asin(jk));
    float hg = 8000;
    hg = hg / 9500;
    printf ("%f\n", asin(hg));
    float rim;
    rim = asin(jk) + asin (hg);
    printf ("%f\n", rim);
    return 0;
}
```

outputting:

```
0.823212
1.001175
1.824387
```

You'll notice I changed `jk = 7700/10500` to `jk = jk/10500` since the latter gave you 0 due to the integer division, but I don't get NaN in either case. You really need to post a *complete* program which shows the errant behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
float jk=7700, ck=8000;
printf ("\n%f",asin(jk/10500));
printf ("\n%f",asin(ck/9500));

float rim;
rim= asin(jk/10500)+ asin(ck/9500);

printf("\n%f", rim);// = nan
}
```

**Output**

```
0.823212
1.001175
1.824387
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is right. The problem is the value of jk and ck.

You kown if |jk/temp|>1 or  |ck/temp|>1, the return of asin(jk/temp) will be nan.

so try to make |jk/temp|<=1 and |ck/temp| <=1, I believe that the return will be ok.